# Simplest Redux-React app in ES5: why aren't props being passed down?

Tags: redux, react-redux

I'm trying to build the most trivial possible Redux app. I have an initial state, I make a Redux store, I pass the store to ReactRedux.Provider, and I have my app as a child of the Provider.

However, my APP view, written as a stateless functional component, is not receiving any props. (The same is true if I write my APP view using `React.createClass` and checking for `this.props` in the `render` method.)

What am I doing wrong?

```js
var initialState = {
  counter: 0
};

var rootReducer = function(state, action) {
  if (!state) state = initialState;
  switch (action.type) {
  default:          // don't do anything yet
    return state;
  }
};

var store = Redux.createStore(rootReducer, initialState);

var APP = function(props) {
  return React.createElement(
    'div',
    {},
    props.counter   // props is not defined
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement(
    ReactRedux.Provider,
    {store: store},
    React.createElement(APP, null)
  ),
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `connect()` function provided by React-Redux to create a wrapped version of your "APP" component that is actually hooked up to the store.  See http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html .

You can write the equivalent logic yourself for subscribing to the store and passing updated props to a component, but generally there's not a good reason to do so.

Comment: Ah, thank you. For some reason I thought that Provider did that for you.

Comment: No, Provider just inserts the store reference into React's "context" feature, which makes it available to any descendant component that asks for it.  The generated wrapper components then look in the context to get the store, and subscribe to its updates.  That's all an implementation detail you shouldn't have to worry about yourself, though.  Just stick `<Provider>` at the top of your component tree, and use `connect()` to wrap any components that need to pull data from the store.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, I am going to add here an example of a working case in codepen not using babel neither the integrated version of jsx.

https://codepen.io/kanekotic/pen/LxbJNJ

Solution ;TL;DR

As commented before there is missing the redux connect

```
var mapstateToProps = function(state) { 
  return{
    counter: state.counter
  }
}
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return Redux.bindActionCreators(ActionCreators, dispatch);
}
var connectedApp = ReactRedux.connect(mapstateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(APP)
```

and use then in the component connectedApp and no APP